# Laravel 8, Model factory class not found

Tags: php, laravel

so when using the new model factories class introduced in laravel 8.x, ive this weird issue saying that laravel cannot find the factory that corresponds to the model. i get this error

```
PHP Error:  Class 'Database/Factories/BusinessUserFactory' not found in .....
```

tho ive followed the laravel docs, ive no idea whats going on

Here is the `BusinessUser` class

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Database\Factories\BusinessUserFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BusinessUser extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

and the factory

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\BusinessUser;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class BusinessUserFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = BusinessUser::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => "dsfsf"
        ];
    }
}
```

any ideas or leads is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the filename of that factory class? did you upgrade to 8 as opposed to a fresh install, if so you are probably missing the autoloading directive for that directory

Comment: the file name is `BusinessUserFactory.php`, yes i upgraded to to laravel 8

Comment: I'm running into a similar error, where in a test that calls a factory updated for Laravel 8, an error is throwing saying that the class "Database\Factories\Entity" not found.

In the factory App\Models\Entity is used.   The autoload has been updated as below.

Comment: in folder factories you need to create factory file which related to seeders

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you upgraded to 8 from a previous version you are probably missing the autoload directive for the `Database\Factories` namespace in `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
},
```

You can also remove the `classmap` part, since it is no longer needed.

Run `composer dump` after making these changes.

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Upgrade Guide - Database - Seeder and Factory Namespace](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#seeder-factory-namespaces)

Comment: What if you've not upgraded to 8 but started a project on version 8 then what could be the issue?

Comment: In addition, the previous `database/seeds` directory should be renamed to `database/seeders`

Comment: It has already been mentioned in @Ahmed Khattab's code but could be easily missed: remember to add `use HasFactory;`

Answer (score 22):

Apparently you have to respect the folder structure as well. For example, if you have the User Model in the following path: `app\Models\Users\User`, then the respective factory should be located in `database\factories\Users\UserFactory`.

Comment: Thank you, It works for me. after change namespaces as the model is located. then run composer dump & php artisan optimize:clear database seeding completed.

Comment: WOW thank you for this I had a brand new setup just scratching my head over this issue

Answer (score 9):

I'm in the process of migrating from laravel 7 to 8.

After banging my head against the wall for a while and looking at the source code, I saw that you can optionally override what factory class gets called for a model using the `newFactory` method on the model.

I also then noticed that it *IS* in the documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#creating-models) - I just didn't understand what it meant the first time I read it. Now I do.

I solved this by the following:

```php
<?php

namespace My\Fancy\Models;

use Database\Factories\SomeFancyFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SomeClass extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /** @return SomeFancyFactory */
    protected static function newFactory()
    {
        return SomeFancyFactory::new();
    }
}
```

After this change, my tests passed as expected.

Comment: I've had to do this, but it's not my favourite.

Comment: I have used hundreds or thousands different SDKs. Laravel is the most unnecessarily complicated one won by its good looking website.

Comment: The easiest/cleanest way to solve this is setting the model manually in your factory.

    protected $model = Model::class;

Comment: @ideerge I can't agree with you. Laravel's weakness is too many changes after the updates (at least for the better most of the time) but has great, good readable documentation compared to the documentation hell of let's say Java. For example look at this article talking about the topic of this thread: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-factories . All you need to do is to copy the examples and refactor it to your project.

Answer (score 6):

You need to ensure that the namespace is the same: as shown below: otherwise this will screw you up big time. The name of the factory is the `name of the model` + `Factory`

e.g. `app\models\User`- will match to `database/factories/UserFactory`

finally ensure you run: `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: This was the case for me. I grouped my classes into subfolders, which was causing the issues here. After adding the same subfolder structure in factories, everything worked out great.

Comment: @SvetoslavStefanov - I am running into a similar issue as you, could you possibly explain how you handled the subfolder structure in factories? Currently, I am using a domain-focused folder structure so my models are contained in src/Domain/Client/Models/Client and laravel ends up searching for the factory in database/factories/Domain/Client/Models/ClientFactory which is preventing me from being able to seed my database

Comment: @SoggyHedgehoggy - my issue was this: I'm having this folder structure:
- Models
- - Organizations
- - - OrganizationMembers
- - Articles
- - - Article
- - - ArticleAttachments

Which should be replicated into the "factories" folder. "factories" folder should equal "Models" folder.
If you see that Laravel is searching for this path, what is stopping you from creating the model there and be able to seed?

Comment: @SoggyHedgehoggy also don't forget to change your Factory's namespace after is being moved.
When you add a new subfolder to your factory class the namespace wouldn't be `namespace Database\Factories` , but it will became `namespace Database\Factories\Client`

Comment: I had the same problem, suddently my tests were not working. I had to fix my folder name from database/Factories to database/factories.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say your model `Example` is under the `App\Example\Models` namespace. If you want ALL of your factories under `database\factories`, then you could define the namespace for your all of factories in your `AppServiceProvider`:

```php
// ...

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Factory::guessFactoryNamesUsing(function (string $modelName) {
            return 'Database\\Factories\\'.class_basename($modelName).'Factory';
        });
    }
}
```

And then in your factory, located in `database/factories/ExampleFactory.php`:

```php
namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class ExampleFactory extends Factory
{
    // ...
}
```

> ...as per this twitter comment (I can't take credit for this solution but sharing the fix!):
> https://twitter.com/ejunker/status/1306007589940068352/photo/1

Comment: I had been struggling for more than 13 hours to find a solution for running Factories and seeders. I attempted to override various methods in the base Factory, but my efforts were unsuccessful. I truly appreciate your generosity in sharing this valuable resource

Answer (score 3):

In my own case, it happened in a Laravel 8 project ie it wasn't a project I upgraded from Laravel 7. And I noticed this after doing `composer update` recently.

1: When creating the model, create the factory alongside

```
php artisan make:model BusinessUser -f // -f creates the factory
```

2: For your older models comment out `use HasFactory;` or just create the factory

```
php artisan make:factory BusinessUserFactory -m
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same issue, but for a different reason. If you're using factories in the `setUp` function of a test, make sure:

1. You're extending `Tests\TestCase` (instead of `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`)
2. The first line of your `setUp` function should be `parent::setUp();` (I was missing this)

Comment: This looks like what would be happening for me - the only time I get this error is when I'm calling the factory in the setup method of the test class.  However, my code is set up like you mentioned here and I'm still getting the error. (Error: Class 'Database\Factories\Entity' not found)

Answer (score 2):

Add this to `AppServiceProvider::boot()` to prevent namespace of model guessing.

```
Factory::guessFactoryNamesUsing(function (string $modelName) {
        return 'Database\\Factories\\' . Arr::last(explode('\\', $modelName)) . 'Factory';
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a laravel core issue ! it was caused by the `modelName()` method located in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory.php`

[image]

Issue was fixed 10 days ago by laravel maintainers in this commit
[Fix commit](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/da28a533751ad28d637f28c6301efe317595d616) and this release [8.82.0](https://github.com/laravel/framework/releases/tag/v8.82.0)

You can fix the issue by upgrading your laravel version to **8.82.0**

Hope this saves you some time. cheers !

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same problem !
Just add this to your Model. It worked for me !

```
protected static function newFactory()
{
    return new ourFactory();
}
```

Comment: I see a symptom tackled, not a cause. Does this necessitate changing the factory mentioned where referring to `ourFactory` before?

Comment: First, you need create a Factory with command php artisan make:factory
For Example with Customer:`php artisan make:factory CustomerFactory --model=Customers`
And add this to your Factory:
`protected $model = customers::class;`
        `return [
            'name' => $this->faker->name(),
            'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail(),
        ];`
Second, make your model seed with command `php artisan make:seed UserTableSeeder` and add this to function run() `customers::factory()->count(20)->create();`
Final, you run comand `php artisan db:seed --class=CustomerTableSeeder`

Comment: @greybard more detail for Factory
(https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-8-using-faker-and-factory)

Answer (score 0):

May be everything is perfect just run `composer dump-autoload`. It happened to me.

Answer (score 0):

my problem was related with composer.lock file that was installing laravel v7, solved it with this command

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this package if you are upgrading  from laravel 7 to 8
composer require laravel/legacy-factories

Answer (score -2):

Today I have got below issue after upgrading my project from `Laravel 7` to `Laravel 8` and updating it online on server.

```
Trait 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory' not found
```

Even I have updated `composer.json` with autoload directive given in answer by @lagbox but it did not resolved the issue for me.

Finally I have updated complete `vendors` folder online that have resolved my issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "updated complete vendors"? How did you upgrade your project without doing that?

Comment: Whenever we update any package offline in Laravel website, we may require to replace vendors folder from offline to online as vendors folder gets new package files in it.

Other way to update vendors folder online on server with terminal but some servers don't support it.

Comment: Please add all such explanation to your answer by editing it - how **exactly** do you do that? "Replace vendor folders" sounds like some manual process that should better be solved through a proper deployment