# Laravel 8 - Class 'Database/Factories/User' not found

Tags: laravel-8

I have this PostFactory.php file in database->factories directory:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;


class PostFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Post::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'user_id'   => User::factory(),
            'title' => $this->faker->sentence,
            'message' => $this->faker->paragraph
        ];
    }
}
```

Now, when I run this command

```
Post::factory()->create();
```

**from the tinker**

I got that error message

> Class 'Database/Factories/User' not found

:( Is there anything I am missing?

[image]

Comment: You haven't defined your `User` model

Comment: @Daniel_Knights You mean I should this `use App\Models\User;`

Comment: Yes, try that and it should work

Comment: Now, I got this error on tinker https://prnt.sc/usstmh

Comment: I can create a User form the tinker: `User::factory()->create()`

Comment: I haven't made factories in the way you have so I don't what's causing that error

Comment: Check out this answer: [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63943758/laravel-8-model-factory-class-not-found)

Answer (score 18):

You need to import the User Model.
For Laravel 8, Your `PostFactory.php` file should look like so;

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;


class PostFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Post::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'user_id'   => User::factory(),
            'title' => $this->faker->sentence,
            'message' => $this->faker->paragraph
        ];
    }
}
```

check [laravel docs on writing factories](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#writing-factories) for more info.

### UPDATE:

As for the error here on [prnt](https://prnt.sc/usstmh) (picked it up in the comments), You will need to provide more information.

However to start you up consider checking your database for:

- A post that does not have a **user_id**. I.e one that you might have added before adding the foreign key constraint and therefore does not belong to any user.

If that's the case consider removing it or use tinker to manually assign a foreign key(i.e associate the post with a user) then try and create factories again. As you are trying to enforce a required column to existing data that does not already have it.

Answer (score 3):

FYI just run:

composer dump-autoload

It can be that the class is not autoloaded.

Comment: More info on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63943957/7230293

Answer (score 0):

As i Also had same Issue .First i changed my factory name same as name of model . Like if we have Blog Model .. We will make BlogFactory . so it can find the name of factory .

Answer (score 0):

Quit and then start again artisan tinker. This worked for me.